# How do I conect a Thunderbolt Display and a HDMI display at the same time?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt-display

I would like to connect a Thunderbolt Display and a Dell 24" display to my MackBook Pro (mid 2011 model) at the same time to use dual screens. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this because your Thunderbolt Display has thunderbolt ports.

Connect your Thunderbold screen to your MacBook Pro and then connect your Dell 24" to the thunderbolt on your Thunderbold display. You will need a thunderbolt to DVI or VGA adaptor.

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried this but apparently you can only daisy chain thunderbolt displays to other thunderbolt displays, I tried it with a thunderbolt to dvi and a thunderbolt to hdmi and neither worked.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a usb to hdmi to the dell at the same time as using the Thunderbolt Display from the thunderbolt port?